# Is it possible to use the .ToUpper() method in C# on a string value that isn't stored in a variable?

Tags: c#, string, switch-statement

I have a program that reads in parameters from a file.  The file is read in one line at a time, and each line is checked to see if it holds a specific value or a blank.  If line isn't blank space, the value in the line is passed to a switch statement.  Here is a part of the swtich statement in question:

```
switch(stName)
        {
            //GENERAL section
            case "JOBNAME":
                _JobName = stValue;
                break;
            case "RUN AS-OF DATE":
                _RunDate = stValue;
                break;
            case "USER NOTIFICATION EMAIL ADDRESS":
                _UserEmailAddr = stValue;
                break;
            default:
                System.Exception ex = new System.Exception("Unexpected parameter");
                ex.Data.Add("Config File", oCommandArgs.ConfigFile);
                ex.Data.Add("Parm Line", stIniLine);
                ex.Data.Add("Delimiter", cDelimiter);
                ex.Data.Add("Name", stName);
                ex.Data.Add("Value", stValue);
                throw ex;

        }
```

The value in stName is converted to upper case prior to going to the switch statement.  My question is, is it possible to use the .ToUpper() method on a string value that isn't stored in a variable?  Basically, so that the code would resemble something like this:

```
    switch(stName)
        {
            //GENERAL section
            case "Jobname".ToUpper():
                _JobName = stValue;
                break;
            case "Run as-of date".ToUpper():
                _RunDate = stValue;
                break;
            case "User notification e-mail address".ToUpper():
                _UserEmailAddr = stValue;
                break;
            default:
                System.Exception ex = new System.Exception("Unexpected parameter");
                ex.Data.Add("Config File", oCommandArgs.ConfigFile);
                ex.Data.Add("Parm Line", stIniLine);
                ex.Data.Add("Delimiter", cDelimiter);
                ex.Data.Add("Name", stName);
                ex.Data.Add("Value", stValue);
                throw ex;

        }
```

This is just to help simplify adding additional parameters.

Comment: `case "Jobname".ToUpper():` - what is the point of that?   Fix that and your question goes away

Comment: While `"Jobname".ToUpper()` is valid it will not work as a case because a case needs to be a constant value.

Answer (score 4):

In a switch statement, the case labels must be compile time constants; the compiler must *know* the result of the expression at compile time. The result of `ToUpper()` can not be, in C#, a compile time constant, code has to *run* in order to know the result, and therefore can't be used as you intend to.

```
const int one = 1;
const char c = 'c';

case 'c':
case c:
case 1:
case one:
case one + 1:
case default(int):
```

Are all valid.

```
int two = 2;
char a = 'a';

case two: //two is a variable
case a: //a is a variable
case 'c'.ToUpper(); //result of ToUpper is not known at compile time
case one.CompareTo(one): //result of CompareTo is not known at compile time
```

Are not.

Most practical solution? Decide on a casing criteria for your labels, write them all uppercase, or lower case, just be consistent, and then simply format accordingly the variable you are switching on:

```
switch(stName.ToUpper()) //<<<normalize casing here
{
    case "JOBNAME":
        _JobName = stValue;
        break;
    case "RUN AS-OF DATE":
        _RunDate = stValue;
        break;
    ...
}
```

If you have have to deal with localized upper and lower casing then use `ToUpperInvariant` or `ToLowerInvariant`. If that is not an option then `switch` is probably not the right tool for the job and you'll want to solve this with regular `if-elseif-else` statements.

Comment: I'd be careful whenever I say "obviously". The only thing obvious to me is that the value is perfectly well defined at compile time ;-). (I suppose one could define it `constexpr` in C++.)

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Point taken, and edited. This is c# though :p

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is 100% possible and valid to do that on a string. You have access to all string methods doing it that way. However, switch statements require a constant value so you would not be able to do that in a switch. I would take a look at your code again and see why you would need it. Why not just write the value in all caps?

EDIT: Switch statements require a constant value so the way you are intending to use is NOT valid.  I have edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: This answer is correct but misses an important point - he can't use it where he is intending to use it, as only constants are permitted in switch statements...

Comment: No it is 100% impossible.  You can't do `case "Run as-of date".ToUpper():` - **it won't compile**.  `case` statements must be **constants** which upvoters on the prior comment seem to have forgotten!

Comment: @MickyD That's precisely what I was saying. His answer is technically correct (you can call string methods on a hardcoded string), but is not useful to the questioner, because you need constants in a switch statement. I even explicitly called that out in my comment `only constants are permitted in switch statements` (although I should have said "case" not "switch" admittedly).

Comment: @RB. I based it at the time of the original answer and his answer was never "correct" with respect to the question and scenario